# Selecting an option in ngOptions doesn't update the model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular1.6

I have a slightly complex object structure:

```
$scope.items = 
[
 {
   name: 'something',
   complexObject:
     {
        number: 1,
        id: 12345
     }
 },
  …more of those
]
$scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[0];
```

Now I want to create a dropdown box like this:

```
<select 
   ng-options="item as item.complexObject.number for item in items track by items.complexObject.id" 
   ng-model="selectedItem">
```

When I updated `selectedItem` with another item, the according number is displayed in the dropdown box. But when I select an item from the box the selectedItem is not updated. What I noticed though is, that all options I pick get the 'selected' tag in the DOM.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("Profile", [] );
                app.controller("ProfileCtrl", function($scope) {
                        $scope.items = 
                                [
                                 {
                                   name: 'something',
                                   complexObject:
                                     {
                                        number: 1,
                                        id: 12345
                                     }
                                 },
                                 {
                                   name: 'something',
                                   complexObject:
                                     {
                                        number: 2,
                                        id: 12345
                                     }
                                 },
                                ]
                        $scope.selectedItem     = {}
                        $scope.selectedItem['val'] = $scope.items[0];
                        $scope.get_info         = function(){
                                alert('Selected Row number "'+JSON.stringify($scope.selectedItem['val'])+'"')
                        }
                })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="Profile" ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
                <select  ng-options="item as item.complexObject.number for item in items"    ng-model="selectedItem['val']"></select>
                <button class="btn" ng-click="get_info()">Click and see whick item selected</button>
        </body>
```

Comment: If you are setting primitive data type value as ng-model value.it will not update automatically ...try to use non-primitive data type value(it will update both the place)

Comment: When I reference my controller as ctrl and acces ctrl.selectedItem, then it works. But ctrl.selectedItem != $scope.selectedItem. Therefore I added watches on both fields that write their value into each other. Not beautiful, but it works. Your approach helped me to find the issue. Thanks.